# sql oracle how to know which part of the query takes long time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a large script that I'm using to get information about Employees, the script consists of lots of lookups and joins between several tables, I'm wondering, is there anyway that I can know which part of the script or which lookup takes more time and make the script very slow so I can only tune it instead of trying to tune the whole script until I find out which one causing me the trouble.

I'm using oracle 11g.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into [`explain plan`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/explain-plan-usage) to find out the execution workflow, and where is the most consuming parts in your query. For example, if you are using SQL Developer, you can run the following:

```
explain plan for
<your query>
```

Then run:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

It will give you the results in a table format, something like this:
[image]

You can look at the time and the cost, and the operation types. For example, whenever you see 'Full table scan' that is a red sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tuning & Diagnostic pack on Enterprise Edition you can use also:

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('<your SQL id>',report_level=>'ALL') plan_table_output from dual;
```

where  is ID of your statement, ex. dk25xwhpxvnwx, actual value can be found in v$sqlarea by sql_full_text column.

It provides actual timing for each step of execution plan, when EXPLAIN PLAIN provides only estimations.

Comment: Note that you need the "Performance and Tuning Pack" for that. Which is an **additional** cost option to the Enterprise Edition